# a erlang actor little demo

Tags: erlang, elixir, actor, erl

I am a rookie in Erlang, tired to write the code for spider:

```erlang
-module(http).
-compile([export_all]).

init() ->
  ssl:start(),
  inets:start(),
  register(m, spawn(fun() -> loop() end)),
  register(fetch, spawn(fun() -> x() end)),
  ok.

start() ->
  L1 = [114689,114688,114691,114690], % detail page id

  lists:map(fun(Gid) ->
    io:format("~p ~n", [Gid]),
    fetch ! {go, Gid}
  end, L1),
  m ! done,
  done.

main(_) ->
  init(),
  start().

loop() ->
  io:fwrite("this is in loop!!"),
  receive
    {no_res, Gid} ->
      io:format("~p no res ! ~n", [Gid]),
      loop();
    {have_res, Gid} ->
      io:format("~p have res ! ~n", [Gid]),
      loop();
    done ->
      io:format("wowowow", [])
  end.

x() ->
  receive
    {go, Gid} ->
      http_post(Gid);
    _ ->
      ready
  end.

http_post(Gid) ->
  URL = "https://example.com", % url demo 
  Type = "application/json",
  ReqArr = ["[{\"id\": \"", integer_to_list(Gid), "\"}]"],
  ReqBody = string:join(ReqArr, ""),

  case httpc:request(post, {URL, [], Type, ReqBody}, [], []) of
    {ok, {_, _, ResBody}} ->
      if
        length(ResBody) =:= 0 ->
          io:format("Y: ~p ~n", [Gid]);
          m ! {no_res, Gid};
        true ->
          io:format("N: ~p ~n", [Gid])
          m ! {have_res, Gid}
      end;
    {error, Reason} ->
      io:format("error cause ~p~n", [Reason]);
    _ ->
      io:format("error cause ~n", [])
  end.
```

Now, when I exceute code, process will terminate at once, log:

[image]

I have two question:

1. How I solve this problem ?
2. If I have tens of thousands of id in `L1` , how solve? Spawn dozens of actors? If yes, how do you decide which actor to `receive` which id?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) Instead of wrapping an anonymous function around `loop()`:

```
register(m, spawn(fun() -> loop() end)),
```

you can call [spawn/3](https://erldocs.com/21.0/erts/erlang.html?i=2&search=spawn#spawn/3):

```
register(m, spawn(?MODULE, loop, []) ),
```

Same here:

```
register(fetch, spawn(fun() -> x() end)),
```

**Nope.  Calling spawn/3 in an escript doesn't work--unless you precompile the script with:**

```
escript -c myscript.erl
```

2) An escript creates a process that executes a `main/1` function that you define.  Your `main/1` function looks like this:

```
main(_) ->
  init(),
  start().
```

The `init()` function doesn't loop so it ends after the all the functions it calls return, i.e. `ssl:start()`, `inets:start()`, `register()`.   Your `start()` function doesn't loop either, so after `start()` returns,  then `main()` returns and because the process executing the `main()` function has nothing left to do, it ends.

3)

> How I solve this problem ?

Http post requests take an eternity in terms of computer processing speeds and there is waiting involved, so you can speed up your code by executing multiple post requests at the same time rather than executing them sequentially.   In erlang, the way you execute things at the same time is to spawn additional processes.  In your case, that would mean spawning a new process for each post request.

Your main process can be an infinite loop that sits in a receive waiting for messages, something like this:

```
main(_) ->
  init(),
  loop().
```

where `init()` looks like this:

```
init() ->
  ssl:start(),
  inets:start(),
  register(loop, self()),
  ok.
```

Then you can create a user interface function like `start()` that spawns the post requests:

```
start() ->
  L1 = [114689,114688,114691,114690], % detail page id

  lists:foreach(fun(Gid) ->
    io:format("~p ~n", [Gid]),
    spawn(?MODULE, http_post, [Gid])
  end, L1).
```

**---Response to comment---**

Here's an example:

```
%First line cannot have erlang code.
main(_) ->
    init(),
    start().

init() ->
    ssl:start(),
    inets:start().

start() ->
    L1 = [1, 2, 3, 4],
    Self = self(),

    Pids = lists:map(fun(Gid) ->
        Pid = spawn(fun() -> http_post(Gid, Self) end),
        io:format("Spawned process with Gid=~w, Pid=~w~n", [Gid, Pid]),
        Pid
    end, L1),

    io:format("Pids = ~w~n", [Pids]),

    lists:foreach(
        fun(Pid) ->
            receive
                {no_res, {Gid, Pid} } ->
                    io:format("no response! (Gid=~w, Pid=~w)~n", [Gid, Pid]);
                {have_res, {Gid, Pid, Reply}} ->
                    io:format("got response: ~p~n(Gid=~w, Pid=~w)~n~n", 
                              [Reply, Gid, Pid]);
                {Pid, Gid, Error} ->
                    io:format("Error:~n(Gid=~w, Pid=~w)~n~p~n", [Gid, Pid, Error])
            end
        end, Pids).

http_post(Gid, Pid) ->
  URL = "http://localhost:8000/cgi-bin/read_json.py", % url demo 
  Type = "application/json",
  ReqArr = ["[{\"id\": \"", integer_to_list(Gid), "\"}]"],
  ReqBody = string:join(ReqArr, ""),

  case httpc:request(post, {URL, [], Type, ReqBody}, [], []) of
    {ok, {_, _, ResBody}} ->
      if
        length(ResBody) =:= 0 ->
          io:format("Y: ~p ~n", [Gid]),
          Reply = {no_res, {Gid, self()} },
          Pid ! Reply;
        true ->
          io:format("N: ~p ~n", [Gid]),
          Reply = {have_res, {Gid, self(), ResBody} },
          Pid ! Reply
      end;
    {error, _Reason}=Error ->
        Pid ! {Gid, self(), Error};
    Other ->
        Pid ! {Gid, self(), Other} 
  end.
```

> If I have tens of thousands of id in L1 , how solve?

The same way.  One hundred thousand processes is not considered a lot of processes in erlang.

Comment: Yeah, your solution is ok. But I must open two erlang shell.

if I want to only use escript execute code to get result like script language like Python or JavaScript ?If escript can't, how other Erlang program get actor result in main progress.

Comment: @riskers, See the full example I added to the bottom of my answer.

Comment: ok, I used to do the same thing in Golang: create 500 channels to deal one hundred thousand http request. Now I spawn 500 actors in Erlang, how to distribute one hundren thousand http request in determinative actors.

Comment: @riskers, I don't think you need to create a thread pool in erlang for http requests, but a thread pool in erlang would be programmed similarly to a thread pool in any other language--the logic is the same.  An erlang worker process would wait in a receive for a message describing the work that needs to be done, e.g. a url, and when there's no more work to be done, you send the worker process a `done`  message, which causes the receive to stop looping, and the worker dies.

Comment: ....Or, you can use a third party library like [poolboy](https://github.com/devinus/poolboy), [poolboy](https://elixirschool.com/en/lessons/libraries/poolboy/)